# Get the time when nohup R program finishes

Tags: linux, shell, terminal, nohup

I want to get the time when program finish. But it always show the same time. Here is my shell script. It always show that `START TIME` is same as `END TIME`.  How do I fix that?

```
START=$(date +"%r") 
nohup Rscript program_1.R >program_1.Rout & wait & echo START TIME = $START\n END TIME = " `date +"%r"`";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending only the R script to the background, date is executed immediately.

Instead of

```
date +%r; sleep 5 & date +%r
```

do

```
date +%r; (sleep 5; date +%r) &
```